# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 928: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, decode

So i'm trying to upload a text file in google collab and I keep getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
!pip install pronouncing
!pip install markovify

from google.colab import files
import markovify
import pronouncing

uploaded = files.upload()
for fn in uploaded.keys():
  text = uploaded[fn].decode()

for i in range(10):
  print(text_model.make_short_sentence(50))
```

Here's the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-734c66054f1c> in <module>()
      5 uploaded = files.upload()
      6 for fn in uploaded.keys():
----> 7   text = uploaded[fn].decode()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 928: invalid start byte
```

Comment: if you know what codec it is in, I think you can pass that as an argument to `.decode()`

Comment: The error message strongly suggests that your text document is not encoded in UTF-8.  Since we don't have your input file available to us, we can't see for ourselves what it is.

Comment: @IanMcLaird Yep it was the text document that wasn't in UTF-8. thank you for the help.

Answer (score -1):

When the same happened to me, I fix it by converting the file to UTF-8.

If you use PyCharm just click in the format (bottom right) > UTF-8 > convert.